# How to use php 'copy' to reduce file size of image

Tags: php, image, copy, filesize

i am using this

```
copy($image, "images/covers/$imagepath.jpeg");
```

But this is creating full size images which will take up some room eventually.

How can i modify this to create a slightly lower res image and reduce file size?

Comment: you should use gd http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

You can open and scale the image to a desired with and height:

```
$imagefile = "/path/to/file/image.jpeg";
$resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagefile);
imagescale($resource, $new_width, $new_height);
// save the resource to desired destination
// the third argument states the quality of the image, can be changed to reduce filesize
imagejpeg($resource, "images/covers/$imagepath.jpeg", 80);
imagedestroy($resource);
```